# Is using Arabic letters in a domain name OK for SEO?

Tags: seo, domains, idn

I want to use Arabic letters in my site's domain name.

Will that be good for search engine optimization? I will be targeting people searching in the Arabic language.

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting the people who are using Arabic language, then yes, it would be good for SEO. If you are targeting other locations that aren't using Arabic language, that's a big no no for SEO.

As simple as that.

Comment: yes its simple all the subject is : the domain not written in non-English letters . it written in english like (xn--bercool-m2a.d ) but the browser who translate it in the non-english names .
so I am affraid if the search engines read it that ( xn--bercool-m2a.d )